# jquery checkbox nested with select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have checkboxes nested with select to change a span value but my problem is when I have two or more selects... I'm not good on javascript =/

How to get the problem: select value 2 on first select after select 2 in second select, and select 0 on second and 0 on first when you do it total has to be 0 but I don't know, how to do it =/

```
<div id="test_div">
<input class="test_class" type="checkbox" value="3,00"/>3,00
<input class="test_class" type="checkbox" value="5,00"/>5,00
<input class="test_class" type="checkbox" value="10,00"/>10,00
<input class="test_class" type="checkbox" value="15,00"/>15,00

<select class="test_class">
    <option value="10,00">0</option>
    <option value="10,00">1</option>
    <option value="10,00">2</option>
</select>
<select class="test_class">
    <option value="10,00">0</option>
    <option value="10,00">1</option>
    <option value="10,00">2</option>
</select>
<select class="test_class">
    <option value="10,00">0</option>
    <option value="10,00">1</option>
    <option value="10,00">2</option>
</select>
<span id="total">0,00</span><br/>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function()
{
   var last = 0;
   $('body').on('change','.test_class', function()
    {
        var vt = parseFloat($('#total').html().replace(',','.'));
        if($(this).is('input:checked'))
        {
           var val = parseFloat($(this).val().replace(',','.'));
           total = val + vt;
        }else if($(this).is('input'))
        {
            var val = parseFloat($(this).val().replace(',','.'));
            total = vt - val;
         }
    if($(this).is('select'))
    {
        var val = parseFloat($(this).val().replace(',','.'));
        var index = $(this).prop('selectedIndex');

    if(index == 0)
    {
        if(last > 0)
        {
            total = vt - val*last;
        }
        last = 0;
    }

    if(index == 1)
    {
        if(last == 2)
        {
            total = vt - val;
        }else
        {
            total = vt + val*index;
        }
        last = 1;
     }

     if(index == 2) 
     {
         if(last == 1)
         {
             total = vt + val;
         }else
         {
             total = vt + val*index;
         }
         last = 2;      
     } 
    }
    total = total.toFixed(2).replace('.',',');
    $('#total').html('').html(total);
    });    
});
```

Example in: http://jsfiddle.net/jvtcc/8/

Comment: all options has the same value??

Comment: Yes, because I do the math in javascript multiplying them...
But it can be changed to first option = 0 second = 10 third = 20 values aren't a problem...

Answer (score 0):

```
$("select .test_class").change(function() {
    var total;
    total = 0;
    $("select .test_class").each(function() {
        total += parseInt($(this).value);
    });
    $("#total").text(total + ".00");
});
```